# Translating Rules from Apache to Nginx

Tags: php, html, apache, nginx, web

I have switched server from Apache to Nginx.

Everything works, except for the last bit.

In Apache I have the following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^event/(.*)$ /event.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/event/(.*)$ /event.html [L]
RewriteRule ^venue/(.*)$ /venue.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/venue/(.*)$ /venue.html [L]
RewriteRule ^calendar/day/(.*)$ /calendar/day.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/calendar/day/(.*)$ /calendar/day.html [L]
RewriteRule ^calendar/month/(.*)$ /calendar/month.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/calendar/month/(.*)$ /calendar/month.html [L]
```

But can't get them right in Nginx. The following is the implementation:

```
location /event {
  rewrite ^/event/(.*)$ /event.html break;
  rewrite ^/event/(.*)$ /event.html break;
}

location /venue {
  rewrite ^/venue/(.*)$ /venue.html break;
  rewrite ^/venue/(.*)$ /venue.html break;
}

location /calendar {
  rewrite ^/calendar/day/(.*)$ /calendar/day.html break;
  rewrite ^/calendar/day/(.*)$ /calendar/day.html break;
  rewrite ^/calendar/month/(.*)$ /calendar/month.html break;
  rewrite ^/calendar/month/(.*)$ /calendar/month.html break;
}
```

But I get redirected to the Home Page when the above are accessed.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the path after the slash is duplicated due to already been defined via `location`. Try simply this:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/event/(.*)$ /event.html last;
    rewrite ^/venue/(.*)$ /venue.html last;
    rewrite ^/calendar/day/(.*)$ /calendar/day.html last;
    rewrite ^/calendar/month/(.*)$ /calendar/month.html last;
}
```